# Migrate from Dedicated Server to Google Cloud Platform. Is that possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration, dedicated-server, dedicated-hosting

My dedicated server will expire soon. I just consider whether to renew it or migrate to Google cloud platform.

There are several points needs to consider:

1. Currently I am using Google Cloud Storage API to host static large files for my website. That will be fine.
2. My website also contain dynamic contents, such as PHP. Will Google supports to host such contents?
3. My website also use WordPress and MySQL database. Will Google support to host such contents?
4. My server is also host mailboxes and mail forwarders. Will Google support to host these?
5. My server is also host several add-on domains via cPanel. Will Google support to host these?
6. To the best, is it possible to use cPanel on Google cloud platform as I am familiar with cPanel.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can migrate a dedicated server to Google Compute Engine. It is possible to run cPanel on a GCE instance. From your question, it sounds like you are used to a *managed* service where they have configured the server for you. GCE is not managed, so you will have to do much more systems administration to set it up and operate the server.

It is not easy to run email on a GCE instance because [outbound port 25 is blocked by default](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).